# Creating a generic service interface that uses generic params

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm trying to use the c# generics to create a generic interface that works as a base to build all my listing services. However I have a problem with the definition.

### The base classes

```
abstract class ListingParams { }

abstract class ListingDTO<T> where T : ListingItemDTO
{
    public List<T> Items{ get; set; }
}

abstract class ListingItemDTO { }
```

### A concrete example

```
class HListingParams : ListingParams { }
class HListing : ListingDTO<HItem> { }
class HItem : ListingItemDTO { }
```

### The interface

```
interface IListingToolsService<in TFilter, out U, V>
    where TFilter : ListingParams
    where U : ListingDTO<V> where V : ListingItemDTO
{
    int Count(TFilter parameters);

    U Get(TFilter parameters);
}
```

**Here starts the problem, due to the Get method returns a generic type, I have to add a third generic parameter to the interface.**

If I want to create a concrete implementation of that interface I have to create something like this:

```
class HListingToolsService : IListingToolsService<ListingParams, HListing, HItem>
{
    public int Count(ListingParams parameters) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public HListing Get(ListingParams parameters) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

However by definition `HListing` is not generic, due to it was defined using `HItem`.

**Is there any way to create that interface with only two parameters in order to don't repeat a type that is already defined?**

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but cant you just omit the V part if the interface as it already handles in the abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code a little bit, convert `ListingDTO<T>` to interface and make generic type parameter `T` covariant. In this case you also should change `Items` type to `IEnumerable<T>`, since `List<T>` is invariant.

```cs
interface IListingDTO<out T> where T : ListingItemDTO
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
}
```

Then implement it in `HListing` class

```cs
class HListing : IListingDTO<HItem>
{
    public IEnumerable<HItem> Items { get; }
}
```

After that you can update `IListingToolsService` interface and get rid of `V` generic type parameter and its constraint

```cs
interface IListingToolsService<in TFilter, out U>
    where TFilter : ListingParams
    where U : IListingDTO<ListingItemDTO>
{
    int Count(TFilter parameters);

    U Get(TFilter parameters);
}
```

Finally implement `HListingToolsService` class

```cs
class HListingToolsService : IListingToolsService<ListingParams, HListing>
{
    public int Count(ListingParams parameters) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public HListing Get(ListingParams parameters) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Covariant declaration of `IListingDTO<out T>` allows you to use `HListing` ( which implements this interface) in service implementation

Comment: @ganchito55 Does it help you? Do you need more details or information?

Comment: Thanks for you answer and the explanation, I used your answer to develop my solution. The problem with this answer is that in many cases the implementation of ``IListingDTO`` is equals so I thought that using a base class was the right way

Answer (score 1):

This might change your design a little bit, but I'd try replacing the following code with something that doesn't take type parameter.
In this way we can encapsulate ListingDTO into a class that doesn't take type parameter directly.

```cs
abstract class ListingItemBase : ListingItemDTO { }

abstract class ListingDTOBase : ListingDTO<ListingItemBase>
{
    public List<ListingItemBase> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And make HListing inherit ListingDTOBase:

```
class HListing : ListingDTOBase { }
```

After that you should be able to define interface without using V type parameter:

```
interface IListingToolsService<in TFilter, out U>
                            where TFilter : ListingParams
                            where U : ListingDTOBase
{
    int Count(TFilter parameters);

    U Get(TFilter parameters);
}
```

And service:

```
class HListingToolsService : IListingToolsService<ListingParams, HListing>
{
    public int Count(ListingParams parameters) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public HListing Get(ListingParams parameters) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that using HListing with Items of type ``ListingItemBase`` force you to cast due to each concrete Item class has different properties.